# Sending data failed. Please try again error when exporting from blazemeter

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

I have recorded the the scenario with blazemeter plugin and then trying to export it into .jmx file, but its giving me error as "Sending data failed. Please try again." Please suggest me how can I export the file into .jmx, and why the error is occurring

Answer (score 2):

First, download the file in json format and then go to http://converter.blazemeter.com/, upload your json file and download it in .jmx format.

P.S.: -it is possible Jmeter throw you an error when you will open the file (so, for this you will need to download a - [plugin.manager.jar](https://jmeter-plugins.org/install/Install/) and from Jmeter -> Options / Plugins Manager install "Throughput Shaping Timer")